# .Net 4.5 and VS2012 Requiring "Global" Namespace Whenever Specifying A Namespace

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, .net-4.5

I've been working on a new MVC 4 project using .Net 4.5 and VS2012, and for a while it was working fine.  But suddenly I'm getting lots of errors like:

```
'System.Web.HttpApplication' is not defined.
```

At first, I thought it was an assembly reference problem, but that all seems fine.  Upon further research, at appears that the Global namespace is being required any time a namespace is specified.  Either of these two forms work just fine:

```
Public Class MvcApplication
    Inherits Global.System.Web.HttpApplication
End Class

Public Class MvcApplication
    Inherits HttpApplication
End Class
```

However, this form will not work for any class:

```
Public Class MvcApplication
    Inherits System.Web.HttpApplication
End Class
```

Does anybody have any ideas?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I figured it out.  I had another assembly that had System as the second part of the assembly name, and the first part was imported into the assembly I was working on.  So anytime I tried to reference System. anything, it was looking in the System namespace of the other assembly instead of the global System namespace.